# An example of compiling a python function to javascript

Tags: javascript, python

Let's suppose I have the following function:

```
def hello():
    print "hello"
```

How would I use a program like `transcript` to translate this into valid javascript?

Answer (score -1):

You can run it by using the following as per the documentation [here](https://www.transcrypt.org/docs/html/installation_use.html) :

```
transcrypt -b hello.py
```

However, this gives me a very odd output:

```
export var hello=function(){print("hello")};hello();
```

I would expect it to give something like:

```
console.log('hello')
```

But this instead is opening up the Print dialogue?

Comment: So, you've self answered, and got it wrong - that's hilarious

Comment: Hi David, you might want to read the tutorial for transcrypt located at https://github.com/bunkahle/Transcrypt-Examples . There is also a starting example for hello.py in here: https://github.com/bunkahle/Transcrypt-Examples/tree/master/hello